# Quack Overflow for localized sites

Tags: support, localization, april-fools, quack-overflow

As far as I see Quack Overflow duck is only available for English-spoken sites. Are there any plans to enable it for localized sites?

Comment: Not until April 2nd!

Comment: How about language sites in addition to the localized ones? I'd like the duck to [learn some Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I think the answer will be the same.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Afraid not. Building this already required a huge investment in Duck-to-English translation work; attempting to find Duck-to-Spanish or Duck-to-Russian translators on short notice simply wasn't feasible for the scheduled launch date.

However, if you happen to know folks skilled in Ducking, don't hesitate to alert them to the need.

Comment: I'm skilled in Ducking.

Comment: @SonicWizard: Quack quack. Quack? Quack quack quack quack.

Comment: @JonEricson April fools!

Comment: @SonicWizard: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSx3U.png

Comment: We need a new language QUIMPLE (Quack-Understanding InterMediate People-LanguagE) that, while not useful on its own, is easy to translate Duck to with minimal loss of meaning, and also possible to translate to various natural human languages with minimal loss of meaning. Then it would only be necessary to translate from QUIMPLE to English, Spanish, Russian, etc. This would carry the further benefits that (a) the duck's overly complex ideas could be simplified by subjecting the generated QUIMPLE to optimization passes and (b) other duck-type languages like Goose could be supported more easily.

Comment: I mean what’s the problem was to make duck strings translatable, like for hats descriptions on Winter Bash?

Comment: Probably because the ducks keep getting tangled up in the strings.

Comment: @alexolut more dev time. April Fools is only one day, compared to over two weeks of Winter Bash. April Fools does not really encourage good behavior, it's just something fun and small.

Comment: DuckDuckGo :):)

Comment: @ShadowWizard good behavior for all, fun for English men only? Duck has a few strings only, so they could be translated quickly by community managers. It doesn’t need too much dev time, just to make strings translatable, such behavior already exist for many things on SE network.

Comment: All our Quacksifex volunteers are duckrolling all sort of quackeries for [December 28](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1202/127) ([localizing the date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_Fools%27_Day#Comparable_prank_days) too)... Some strings may have quackle losing a swim condition, but we have proposed an alternative **[here](https://goo.gl/F8ciNA)**.